# Sort array of arrays with documents using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

I've an array with arrays of documents in it, can some help me on how to sort those arrays with multiple documents inside the array. The user can chose of the type to be searched on. If they can choose 'A' sort all the array items by value associated with type 'A', similarly for the other types. What is the best way to do this. Lodash solution would be highly beneficial. Those values can be integers/strings/guids/datetime fields.

Type is always a string, in any case I don't think it does really matter.

```
[
 [{type:A, value:10},{type:B, value:20},{type:C, value:15},{type:D, value:20}],
 [{type:A, value:5},{type:B, value:10},{type:C, value:35},{type:D, value:40}],
 [{type:A, value:30},{type:B, value:30},{type:C, value:25},{type:D, value:30}],
 [{type:A, value:20},{type:B, value:50},{type:C, value:55},{type:D, value:10}]
]
```

Desired out put if sorted by type 'A'

```
[[{type:A, value:5},{type:B, value:10},{type:C, value:35},{type:D, value:40}],
     [{type:A, value:10},{type:B, value:20},{type:C, value:15},{type:D, value:20}],
     [{type:A, value:20},{type:B, value:50},{type:C, value:55},{type:D, value:10}],
     [{type:A, value:30},{type:B, value:30},{type:C, value:25},{type:D, value:30}]]
```

Comment: Please show the desired output

Comment: Are `A,B,C,D` supposed to be strings or other objects?

Comment: are the inner arrays always sorted by type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a lodash solution that uses [sortBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy) for sorting and [find](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find) to get the corresponding values with a specific `type`.

```
var result = _.sortBy(data, function(item) {
  return _.find(item, { type: 'A' }).value;
});
```

```js
var data = [
  [{
    type: 'A',
    value: 10
  }, {
    type: 'B',
    value: 20
  }, {
    type: 'C',
    value: 15
  }, {
    type: 'D',
    value: 20
  }],
  [{
    type: 'A',
    value: 5
  }, {
    type: 'B',
    value: 10
  }, {
    type: 'C',
    value: 35
  }, {
    type: 'D',
    value: 40
  }],
  [{
    type: 'A',
    value: 30
  }, {
    type: 'B',
    value: 30
  }, {
    type: 'C',
    value: 25
  }, {
    type: 'D',
    value: 30
  }],
  [{
    type: 'A',
    value: 20
  }, {
    type: 'B',
    value: 50
  }, {
    type: 'C',
    value: 55
  }, {
    type: 'D',
    value: 10
  }]
];

var result = _.sortBy(data, function(item) {
  return _.find(item, { type: 'A' }).value;
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In plain Javascript, you could look for the given type and sort by the corresponding value.

```js
function sort(data, type) {
    function getValue(array) {
        var value = -Number.MAX_VALUE;
        array.some(function (o) {
            if (o.type === type) {
                value = o.value;
                return true;
            }
        });
        return value;
    }

    data.sort(function (a, b) {
        var aa = getValue(a),
            bb = getValue(b);
        return isFinite(aa) && isFinite(bb) ? aa - bb : aa.localeCompare(bb);
    });
}


var data = [[{ type: 'A', value: 10 }, { type: 'B', value: 20 }, { type: 'C', value: 15 }, { type: 'D', value: 'b' }], [{ type: 'A', value: 5 }, { type: 'B', value: 10 }, { type: 'C', value: 35 }, { type: 'D', value: 'a' }], [{ type: 'A', value: 30 }, { type: 'B', value: 30 }, { type: 'C', value: 25 }, { type: 'D', value: 'd' }], [{ type: 'A', value: 20 }, { type: 'B', value: 50 }, { type: 'C', value: 55 }, { type: 'D', value: 'c' }]];

sort(data, 'A');
console.log(data);
sort(data, 'D');
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You might want to move `getValue` up one scope, to avoid it being created on every single comparison.

Comment: Thank you Nina, but this is only working for numeric data types. I want it for all data types. Like strings, guids, dates.

Comment: then you need to check the type and sort accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create a relationship for sorting using closures.

```
function sortBy(key){
    return function(a,b){
        return a[key] - b[key];
    }
}

var index = {'A':0, 'B': 1, … };
var userPickedType = 'A';
yourarray.sort(sortBy(index[userPickedType]));
```